# Are there any examples using the Zend/Code/Generator component

Tags: zend-framework

I use Symfony's console component together with the Zend_CodeGenerator component. There was very few examples but I got it work -- http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.codegenerator.html. Of course it didn't handle namespaces and `use` statements. Today I figured I try [Zend/Code/Generator](http://goo.gl/CPNTx). I found an old post here  http://mwop.net/blog/261-Code-Generation-with-ZendCodeGenerator.html.

So using Composer I installed the component and went about updated my code (see below). I'm having issues with doc blocks not being generated (see new version). There's no resulting errors indicating the parameters are wrong just no docblocks. I quickly reviewed the source code, api and even some the unit tests. So before I give up on this and stick with ZF1 CodeGenerator I wondered if there are any examples out there using docblocks.

**Old Version**

```
<?php
$class = new Zend_CodeGenerator_Php_Class();
$docblock = new Zend_CodeGenerator_Php_Docblock(array(
    'shortDescription' => 'Index controller',
    'tags' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'category',
            'description' => 'Controller',
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'package',
            'description' => 'Application\Controller',
        ),
    ),
));
$methods = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'indexAction',
        'docblock' => new Zend_CodeGenerator_Php_Docblock(array(
            'shortDescription' => 'Index action',
            'tags' => array(
                new Zend_CodeGenerator_Php_Docblock_Tag_Return(array(
                    'datatype' => 'void',
                )),
            ),
        )),
    ),
);
$class->setName("Admin_IndexController")
      // Additional step needed to add namespace and use statement
      ->setExtendedClass('Action')
      ->setDocblock($docblock)
      ->setMethods($methods);
$file = new Zend_CodeGenerator_Php_File(array(
    'classes'  => array($class),
));
$code = $file->generate();
// Remove all that extra blank lines
$code = preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $code);
if (file_put_contents('application/modules/admin/controllers/IndexController.php', $code)) {
    $this->output->writeln(
        'Controller generated ' . realpath('application/modules/admin/controllers/IndexController.php')
    );
}
```

**New Version**

```
<?php
$classGenerator = new ClassGenerator(); 
$classGenerator->setName('Admin_IndexController')
               ->setExtendedClass('Action')
               ->setDocBlock(
                    new DocBlockGenerator(
                        'Index controller',
                        '',
                        array(
                            new Tag(
                                array(
                                    'name' => 'category', 
                                    'description' => 'Controller'
                                )
                            ),
                            new Tag(
                                array(
                                    'name' => 'package', 
                                    'description' => 'Application\Controller'
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
               )
               ->addMethods(
                    array(
                        new MethodGenerator(
                            'indexAction',
                            array(),
                            null,
                            null,
                            new DocBlockGenerator(
                                'Index action'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                );          
$fileGenerator = new FileGenerator();
$fileGenerator->setUse('Application\Controller\Action')
              ->setClass($classGenerator);
$code = $fileGenerator->generate();
// ...
```

Comment: You can try with the v2 shipped with ZF2

Comment: Do you mean a different branch or something for zf2?

Comment: The Zend\Code component shipped with ZF2, has been refactored and may your issue is fixed

Comment: Maks3w, my question was about using ZF2's component and the issue I was having with docblocks, and if there were any examples out there. Do you have any?

Comment: Well, sorry but Zend_CodeGenerator_Php_Class is the name of a ZF1 classname. You can find more examples in the test suite of the component

Comment: No worries Maks3w, if you look at the question you see the old and new versions of my code and I mentioned I already took a look at the tests for Zend\Code but they dont show examples of using docblocks together with the individual generators, which is understandable -- there called unit tests for a reason. I asked if there were any (complete) examples. Thanks.

Comment: May ZF2 don't give the same support than ZF1 version of the component. Zend\Code in ZF2 is not complete